# Use variable assigned a value inside try catch block later in application?

Tags: java, try-catch

So I'm trying to use my variable n after my try-catch, but I can't because my compiler is complaining that my `n` variable 'might not have been initialized'. How can I fix this? Here is the code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n;

    boolean validInput = false;
    String scanner;

    while (!validInput) {
        scanner = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert an integer:");
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(scanner);
            validInput = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not an integer!");
            validInput = false;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(n); //I can't use the n even though I give it a value inside my try-catch
}
```

Comment: Just initialize like this int n = 0;

Comment: @cozla Post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You merely need to initialize it beforehand:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = 0;

    boolean validInput = false;
    String scanner;

    while (!validInput) {
        scanner = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert an integer:");
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(scanner);
            validInput = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not an integer!");
            validInput = false;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(n); //I can't use the n even though I give it a value inside my try-catch
}
```

---

On a side note, you don't need to have a `validInput` variable at all.  If you use `continue` and `break` statements, you also won't need to initialize the variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;

    String scanner;

    while (true) {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please insert an integer:");
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(scanner);
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not an integer!");
            continue;
        }
    }

    s.close();

    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The info on break and continue was really helpful! That was really the answer I was looking for :3

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize n.

```
int n = 0;
...
```